# node js: access json if variable name in string?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, variables

I have json object as following

```
var data = { 
   datetime:{
     time:"9:30 AM",
     date:"24-09-2017"
   }
}
```

and i have string `var element = "data.datetime.time"`how to access the time  using element .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string (dot as separator), and use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to extract the data from the object:

```js
var data = { 
   datetime:{
     time:"9:30 AM",
     date:"24-09-2017"
   }
}

var element = "data.datetime.time";

var result = element.split('.').reduce(function(r, p) {
  return typeof r === 'object' ? r[p] : null; // if r is an object, return the prop value, if not return null
}, { data: data });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Function(`return ${element}`)()
```

Comment: sorry I have done typo...its really working..thank you @guest271314

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer for this..

simply we can use  eval()

```
var data = {    
      datetime:{
        time:"9:30 AM",
         date:"24-09-2017"    
      } 
   }

var element = "data.datetime.time";

console.log(eval(element));
```